# PLSQL: How to go line by line through a cursor, copying the values onto a table and on the same loop saving those values into variables?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to go through c_ProdutosEncomenda cursor line by line, copying this values into a table I've created and saving those values on variables so that I can use them to call a function to give me a particular value.

[image: PL/SQL code]

Assuming all values/tables were created correctly, and that I have the "end loop" and "close c_ProdutosEncomenda" commands at the bottom, what's missing here?

It's giving out the following error:

[image: Errors]

The code in question:

```
    create or replace Procedure proc_nota_encomenda(p_id_notaEncomenda in NotaEncomenda.cod_notaEncomenda%TYPE)

   IS

   cursor c_ProdutosEncomenda IS
   Select Distinct f.cod_armazem, nep.cod_produto
    from notaencomenda ne join
    funcionario f on ne.cod_funcionario=f.cod_funcionario
    join NotaEncomenda_Produto nep on ne.cod_notaencomenda=nep.cod_notaencomenda;   

   ex_cod_notaEcomenda_n_existe EXCEPTION;
   codigo_encomenda number;    
   ProdutosEncomenda c_ProdutosEncomenda%ROWTYPE;
   stockArmazem number;
   stockMinimo number;
   stockPedido number;    
   armazem number;
   produto number;

   Begin

   Select cod_notaencomenda into codigo_encomenda from NotaEncomenda where cod_notaEncomenda=p_id_notaEncomenda;

   If (codigo_encomenda!=p_id_notaEncomenda) THEN

   raise ex_cod_notaEcomenda_n_existe;

   end if;   

   Open c_ProdutosEncomenda;

    Loop

       Fetch c_ProdutosEncomenda INTO ProdutosEncomenda;

       Exit when c_ProdutosEncomenda%NotFound;        

       Select cod_armazem from ProdutoEncomenda into armazem;
       Select cod_produto from ProdutosEncomenda into produto;

       stockArmazem:= FUNC_STOCK_ARTIGO_ARMAZEM(produto,armazem);        

       Select stock_minimo INTO stockMinimo FROM Stock where Produto_cod_produto=ProdutosEncomenda.cod_produto

       AND Armazem_cod_Armazem=ProdutosEncomenda.cod_armazem;        

       Select quantidade INTO stockPedido FROM NotaEncomenda_Produto WHERE cod_produto=ProdutosEncomenda.cod_produto

       AND cod_notaEncomenda=p_id_notaEncomenda;            

       If stockArmazem-stockPedido<stockMinimo THEN                

       Insert into ProdutosEmFalta Values (ProdutosEncomenda.cod_produto,p_id_notaEncomenda,stockPedido);           

       Else

               Insert into GuiaSaida (cod_notaEncomenda) Values (ProdutosEncomenda.cod_produto);
               Insert into ZonaArmazem_Produto_GuiaSaida (cod_produto,id_guia,quantidadeRetirada) 
               Values (ProdutosEncomenda.cod_produto,ProdutosEncomenda.cod_armazem,stockPedido);

           end if;

       end loop;
    Close c_ProdutosEncomenda;

   Exception

   when ex_cod_notaEcomenda_n_existe then

       raise_application_error(-20001,'Nota de encomenda inexistente');    end;
```

Comment: thanks! I still don't have the accepted answer I just want it to pass the errors on the Select part...
My idea is to iterate through the table, adding each value to their respective variables so I can have generate results while going through the lines of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is ProdutosEncomenda? I can only guess it is a variable of some record type. If that's the case then you should not select from it. Instead you can simply get specific field values like this:

```
armazem := ProdutosEncomenda.cod_armazem;
produto := ProdutosEncomenda.cod_produto;
```

But it would be really easier if you showed the whole code (and not as an image as a_horse_with_no_name is suggesting). It's good that you attached the errors, but I don't even know which lines they refer to

Comment: I've added the code now :) 

ProdutosEncomenda is supposed to be a new table where to copy each line of the cursor.

Thanks for the tips! I'm a bit of a noob here...

Comment: Doing it the way you proposed did indeed solve it and it's compiling! Joyous day!

Comment: Now all I have to do is asser that the result is correct x) meanwhile thank you very much for unblocking me!